# Adding target to UIButton from category

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm implementing a function to create a custom `UIAlertView`. I have extended `UIView` with a `category`, and I'm creating my method, called

`- (void)showCustomAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString *)message`

I want to add a selector to a button inside my custom alertview, but this selector is contained in my `UIViewController`. Should I move the selector into the category, or somehow reference it in the `viewcontroller`? And If I move the selector into the category, I won't be able to access the `navigationcontroller`...

in **UIView+Category.m:**

```
- (void)showCustomAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString *)message 
{
    UIView *alert = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width/2)-100, (self.frame.size.height/2)-50, 200, 100)];
    UIButton *confirmButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,40, 50, 50)];
    [confirmButton addTarget:self action:@selector(delete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [alert addSubview:confirmButton];
    [self addSubview:alert];
}
```

selector method in **MyViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)delete:(id)sender 
{
     [[self.view viewWithTag:-7] removeFromSuperview];
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are bumping up against the limitations of categories. You can't add instance variables to a class in a category, so you don't have a clean way to save a pointer to your presenting view controller.

I would suggest adding a new method to your category:

```
- (void) addButtonWithTitle: (NSString*) title 
  target: (id) target 
  action: (SEL) action 
  forControlEvents: (UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

Then in the implementation of that method, use the parameters that are passed in to create and configure the button. The method includes a target, selector, and list of events that should trigger the action.

Comment: so how would I access this newly created button in my category method? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've edited my question to show more of my custom alert method.

Answer (score 0):

The selector should be implemented in your viewController , since you could be using your alertView in different viewControllers. Therefore sometimes you would need to perform a logic specific to that viewController. Also MVC 101 forbids you from trying to implement an action in a UIView subclass. Therefore again your viewController should implement the action.