# Writing NSAttributedString to Dropbox file iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

How can I write an attributed string to a Dropbox file? I'm trying to create a header for my file, but I don't know how to change the text format within the Dropbox file.

Something like:

```
    DBPath *newPath = [[DBPath root] childPath:@"hello.txt"];
    DBFile *file = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:newPath error:nil];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Roman" size:14.0];
    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                                forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Title" attributes:attrsDictionary];
    if (file)
        [file writeString:string error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSAttributedString does not have methods to read/write to a file directly. However it does conform to the NSCoding protocol so it's possible to serialize it to a file, with code like this:

```
[NSkeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: string toFile: myFilePath];
```

And then to read it back:

```
NSAttributedString *string = 
  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: myFilePath];
```

Note that the file format is not suitable for exchanging styled text with other platforms/applications. If you archive an attributed string using NSkeyedArchiver, the only thing you can do with the resulting file is to unarchive it with NSKeyedUnarchiver;

Comment: thanks for the information. Would you mind respond to my comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170800/adding-target-to-uibutton-from-category when you have a free moment? It would be incredibly helpful.